# Getting data year wise in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need result for specific year while querying a DATE column

for ex:

```
         select year_last_renovated from project 
         where year_last_renovated='2014';
```

NOTE: YEAR_LAST_RENOVATED is DATE datatype.

Comment: any good reason for voting down this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easy solution:

```
           select year_last_renovated from project where 
           to_char(i.last_renovated,'YYYY')='2014'
```

If you want to show only year in your result then:

```
          select extract(year from year_last_renovated) year_last_renovated 
          from project

                               or

          select to_char(year_last_renovated, 'YYYY') year_last_renovated 
           from project
```